# 'Pointer to member' error C++

Tags: c++, class, switch-statement

I need some help with this error, I don't understand what has to be done to get rid of it. I am trying to build [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/12974/) code  - the last exercise, Graduation. Here is my code:

```C++
// Bunnies.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
// Male = 0;  Female = 1

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;

int num;

class bunny {
    int val;
    int gender;
    int colour;
    int age;
    int type;
    bool radioBun;
    string name;

public:
    void create() {
        val = num;

        age = 1;
        gender = rand() % 2;
        switch (rand() % 100) {
        case 1: radioBun = true;
            break;
        case 2: radioBun = true;
            break;
        default: radioBun = false;
            break;
        }

        if (gender = 0) {
            switch (rand() % 20) {
            case 0: name = "Bob";
                break;
            case 1: name = "Alexis";
                break;
            case 2: name = "William";
                break;
            case 3: name = "Cleo";
                break;
            case 4: name = "Mark";
                break;
            case 5: name = "Jarod";
                break;
            case 6: name = "Billie";
                break;
            case 7: name = "Nathan";
                break;
            case 8: name = "Richard";
                break;
            case 9: name = "Thomas";
                break;
            case 10: name = "Rudolf";
                break;
            case 11: name = "Troy";
                break;
            case 12: name = "Wesley";
                break;
            case 13: name = "Jacob";
                break;
            case 14: name = "Cody";
                break;
            case 15: name = "Gavin";
                break;
            case 16: name = "Norris";
                break;
            case 17: name = "Matt";
                break;
            case 18: name = "Colton";
                break;
            case 19: name = "Daniel";
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            switch (rand() % 20) {
            case 0: name = "Cecila";
                break;
            case 1: name = "Scarlet";
                break;
            case 2: name = "Abby";
                break;
            case 3: name = "Sandra";
                break;
            case 4: name = "Melissa";
                break;
            case 5: name = "Lizabeth";
                break;
            case 6: name = "Susie";
                break;
            case 7: name = "Cherly";
                break;
            case 8: name = "Kaitlin";
                break;
            case 9: name = "Debbie";
                break;
            case 10: name = "Evalyn";
                break;
            case 11: name = "Amalia";
                break;
            case 12: name = "Mendy";
                break;
            case 13: name = "Nora";
                break;
            case 14: name = "Brigitte";
                break;
            case 15: name = "Ebony";
                break;
            case 16: name = "Beatrice";
                break;
            case 17: name = "Tiffany";
                break;
            case 18: name = "Ying";
                break;
            case 19: name = "Kesha";
                break;
            }
        }
        }
    void printCreate() {
        cout << "Bunny "; 
        cout << val;
        cout << " was zapped into existence!" << endl;
    }
};



int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    for (int x = 0; x == 10; x++) {
        num = x;
        bunny num;
        num.create();

        num.printCreate;
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am working out a way to create 10 bunnies at the start of the code, by creating a variable `num`. The for loop runs 10 times, everytime increasing `num` by +1. Each time creating a new instance of the class `bunnies` and assigning the value of num to the name of that instance.

The `void create()` is not giving me any problems, its when I try to do `void printCreate()` that I get this error. It just comes up with "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3867   'bunny::printCreate': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    Bunnies c:\users\bob\source\repos\bunnies\bunnies\bunnies.cpp   145 
". I have looked this up, but I can't understand how to fix this error. Could someone please tell me how to fix this in simple terms?

Comment: Method call is missing `()` at the end. `num.printCreate;` should be `num.printCreate();`

Comment: Read your compiler error messages... and @Mahesh is right.

Comment: Having made the call work, consider looking up `std::array` or `std::vector`, which will help you reduce this to about a half dozen lines of code.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin I don't know about vectors, but how is it possible to use arrays to make the code shorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `num.printCreate;` in your loop by `num.printCreate();`.

Comment: Ahh thanks for that, I always forget to add the two brackets at the end... Ok, so I did that, but it still doesn't print anything out in the terminal. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The condition in your for loop is wrong, the loop gets executed if the condition is true, not if it is false.

Comment: Why is it false?

Comment: Okay, I get what you mean, I changed it to x <=10, now it works.